# "Cannot resolve" errors while running 2 builds in parallel

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have 2 builds running in parallel (aimed to `build/server/` (`target: 'node'`) and `build/client/` (`target: 'web'`), so there should be no files intersection), and sometimes (that's the weird part – only sometimes) I have the following:

```
WARNING in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/bufferutil in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 8:19-57

WARNING in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/default/bufferutil in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 10:19-57

WARNING in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/validation in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/Validation.js 8:19-57

WARNING in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/default/validation in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:19-57

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 14:9-22

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 16:12-36

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js 14:10-24

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/lib/WebSocket.js 13:9-22

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/~/options/lib/options.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in test/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/options/lib
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/~/socket.io-client/~/engine.io-client/~/ws/~/options/lib/options.js 6:9-22
```

running the same in series is ok only when `client` build was completed before the `server`.

I have tried to figure it out by myself with no luck... AFAIU there are two `socket.io` versions for different web/node targets and somehow they are messed up.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? How are you triggering the parallel processes?